# Login failed for User 18456 State 5. User id works on other machines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, logins, datagrip, credentials

I have a really weird login issue I've been pursuing. I experience this only on my Macbook Pro (2018) and only when logging into this one specific SQL Server 2016 database directly through a database client.

Login attempts through any database client to this specific database are met with:

> Login failed for user ''. (Msg 18456, Level 14).

Failure state is 5, "invalid user id".

These credentials work fine when used as credentials for a local copy of the java application that this DB backs.

These credentials work fine when used to login from another machine.

User ID/password does not work **only** when used to log in through a database client, and **only** on my machine. Tested with DataGrip and SQLPro for SQL Server. Both applications can log into other SQL Server databases without issues.

I generated a new user account to no avail. The issue persists. I can connect to other database servers through 1433, and my application can connect to **this** database when running locally with the same credentials

I am connected through a VPN, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

I would suspect that it's some kind of encoding issue with the request, but the problem persists across multiple applications.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15) it could be:

> The error reason An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed.
>   Server is configured for Windows authentication only. can be returned
>   in the following situations.
>
> - When the server is configured for mixed mode authentication, and an ODBC connection uses the TCP protocol, and the connection does not
>     explicitly specify that the connection should use a trusted
>     connection.
> - When the server is configured for mixed mode authentication, and an ODBC connection uses named pipes, and the credentials the client
>     used to open the named pipe are used to automatically impersonate the
>     user, and the connection does not explicitly specify that the
>     connection should use a trusted connection.
>
> To resolve this issue, include `TRUSTED_CONNECTION = TRUE` in the
>   connection string.